# GList Behaviour Error - invalid next size (normal)

Tags: c, pointers, gtk, glib, gnome

I was using Gnome libglib for one of my projects and encountered a weird error. The number of elements that I can enter into a GList looks to be limited to 45. At the 45th element, it gives this error

```
40 counter
41 counter
42 counter
43 counter
44 counter
45 counter
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (normal):   0x0000000001be7e00 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here is the function that produces this error

```
`GList* getMeAGlist(int size)
{
    GList* test = NULL;

    printf("%d\n",size);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%d counter\n",i);
        test  = g_list_append(test,NULL);
    }
    return test;
}`
```

- Is there a limit to the number of elements that can be inserted into a GList? (am I supposed to be allocating the list differently?)
- I have tried setting ulimits, memory limits are set to 'unlimited'
- I have tried this code on multiple machines, it exits at the 45th element
- I am using the latest GLib release

Highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The code you included looks fine and GLib doesn't have a limitation like this: I can easily call your function with 100000 as the argument and it works (I didn't try with a larger number only because using `g_list_append()` is slow with large lists).

From the error message I'm guessing you are trying to call `free()` on something that isn't allocated with `malloc()` and friends or is already freed. Have you tried the above function without any other code -- just a main() that calls your function and returns?

Comment: I have not freed the memory allocated, but this code is a part of many other things happening in the code.

What can be the possible cause for this memory corruption to occur? any ideas?

Comment: The problem is not in the code you pasted here. The error message implies that your heap is corrupted: you may be freeing memory when you shouldn't, or writing past the end of allocated memory... I would review all memory allocation, freeing, copying/writing. If that doesn't help, try valgrinds memcheck.